# Java: FileNotFoundException ends completely

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I've been stuck with this error for 3 hours, it is because in my CSE course we just learned to put in "throws FileNotFoundException" in methods however in my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
  intro();
  prompt(user);
  }
public static void prompt(Scanner user) throws FileNotFoundException {
  boolean game = true;
  while(game != false) {
     System.out.print("(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? ");
     String answer = user.next();
     answer = answer.toUpperCase();      
     if(answer.equals("C")) {
        create(user);
     } else if(response == "V") {
        view(user);
     } else if(answer.equals("Q")) {
           game = false;
     }
  }
}
  public static void create(Scanner user) throws FileNotFoundException {
  System.out.print("Input file name: ");
  String fileName = user.nextLine();
  Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
  File f = new File(fileName);
  if(!f.exists()) {
     System.out.print("File not found. Try again: ");
     fileName = user.nextLine();
     f = new File(fileName);
  }
  System.out.print("Output file name: ");
  PrintStream ot = new PrintStream(new File(user.nextLine()));
  filing(user, fileName, ot);
}
```

When ran through, and inputting in C: this is what happens.

```
Welcome to the game of Mad Libs.
I will ask you to provide various words
and phrases to fill in a story
The result will be written to an output file

(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? c
Input file name: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
    at MadLibs.create(MadLibs.java:47)
    at MadLibs.prompt(MadLibs.java:35)
    at MadLibs.main(MadLibs.java:16)
```

Really confused for this in my CSE class, and I feel like they did not explain the process enough even after asking questions. Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are getting an empty `fileName`. Print out what it is.

Comment: I agree with @Thilo.  It appears you are not entering a file name.

Comment: To add to the above comments. I would try to hard code the file name and see if it works, then you can troubleshoot why the scanner is not giving you the correct input if that is the case.

Comment: You are not actually being prompted to type the filename. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change the "fix" the following line:

`String answer = user.next();`

to read:

`String answer = user.nextLine();`

This means you will capture the newline, meaning it won't be buffered until the next Scanner call (preventing you from reading the filepath prompt).

Then some fixing here too. No need to create a new Scanner, you already have one which you can use:

```
System.out.print("Input file name: ");
String fileName = user.nextLine();
File f = new File(fileName);
if(!f.exists()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `user.next()` to get the user input at first the scanner is reading the only next character but not the newline character.

So later on in your code when you do:

```
System.out.print("Input file name: ");
String fileName = user.nextLine();
```

The `user.nextLine()` call is just reading in the newline character left behind by the `user.next()` call.

One way you can fix this is by reading nextLine but ignoring the input like so:

```
user.nextLine();
System.out.print("Input file name: ");
String fileName = user.nextLine();
```

Now when prompted for the file name it will work correctly.